How should I publish a parent module?
Since the Maven tool does not automatically exclude transitive dependencies at binary-compile-time + publishing and neither does Gradle, I understand the need to divide between "core" and "dependent" submodules.
Artifact (io.github.org.artifact)
 │
 ├── build.gradle
 ├── settings.gradle
 ├── gradle.properties
 ├── Core (io.github.org.artifact-core)
 │   └── build.gradle
 └── Dependent (io.github.org.artifact-dependent)
     └── build.gradle

The issue is that... (from what I've heard... and even as a personal conclusion based on the evidence and practices across the board... ) it would be perfectly reasonable to ALSO publish the "whole" as a single artifact.
dependencies {
   implementation('io.github.org:artifact:1.0.5')
}

But also...
dependencies {
   implementation('io.github.org:artifact-core:1.0.2')
   implementation('io.github.org:artifact-dependent:1.0.3')
}

(
Assume dependent as a module that implements other dependencies, and core as an artifact that DOESN'T.
In this case, artifact is used as a grouping device, facilitating the implementation of both under a single coordinate reference.
)
In reality these are 3 different artifacts, but keep in mind that core and dependent where already 2 separate artifacts in Maven Central's eyes, and their apparent relationship was just merely defined by naming convention ALONE (The "-" between "artifact" and "core" in this example), I see no issue on publishing "the whole" artifact as a single unit.
As far as I know, doing this via the parent's publish task in its own build.gradle file, will trigger both submodule's own publish task... ... ... end of story.
It seems defining the parent's settings.gradle as:
rootProject.name = 'artifact' 
include 'artifact-core' 
include 'artifact-dependent'

...will just make the parent's build.gradle aware that calling \gradlew publish on the parent should call each submodule's publish task independently, but NOT publishing the whole project as a whole.
The main idea is to have an artifact as if the project structure was:
Artifact (io.github.org.artifact)
 │
 ├── build.gradle
 ├── settings.gradle
 ├── gradle.properties
 └── src
      └── main
           └── java
                ├── core
                └── dependent

In the end, the branching is not too important since Maven seems to remove everything between /src/ to /java/ so that imports look like artifact.core.SomeClass
The ideal would be for a build.gradle that, upon calling publish would upload 3 artifacts of coordinates:
io.github.org:artifact-core:1.0.0
io.github.org:artifact-dependent:1.0.0
io.github.org:artifact:1.0.0

Is this possible to do via parent build.gradle (aka. using the same project directory structure)? or should I create 3 submodules with their own build.gradle each and the third branch being simply a copy-paste of the other 2 contents into a single branch?

The default behaviour is to publish the 3 jars - each only containing their respective sources.
It appears that when you state - "whole" so as to use only a single dependency, you actually want a Uber Jar (a single jar with code from all modules).
you can do that by creating an additional jar task that can combine the 3 modules in the root project (archive) - say with name artefact-all or using classification all
refer https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example

Thanks for your help.
In all the projects I've seen that do this. I've never seen them include actual publishing logic. and my guess is that, since the building logic is manually being done, the created JAR is being stripped for a normal Gradle build lifecycle.
Not even the Spring-Framework library contains publishing logic.
I am sure that with enough custom task scripting, Gradle could in theory not only build an Uber from all the submodules, but run the tests, sign in to the remote repo and sign the binary with the GPG's, finally creating an XML pom from scratch.
...

Finally submitting to Maven Central or some other Artifact repo.
But I think I've found a second alternative: I think the project option would require an exclusive branch artifact, that would encompass the totality of all sub-artifacts in the parent module.
Now my only concern is about the sequence in which a gralde publish would execute the individual tasks, since the "Uber-branch" would need to be compiled LAST.
